# How to install .apk file using android AVD.?

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-virtual-device

I am using windows 7. One of my client gave me a apk file to see a previous project developed by another developer. But I have no android phone. So I want to install that apk file to my AVD device of my android sdk. But I am fail. Please give me details instruction how to install apk file inside AVD device of Eclipse(Android SDK). I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

The command is:

adb install app.apk

If you want to install it over an existing installation, you will need:

adb install -r app.apk

This will only work if the installed app and the new app.apk file are signed with the same signature. Otherwise you'll have to uninstall the existing app first.

Make sure that you have `[android installation]\platform-tools` on your PATH. If you don't want to modify your PATH, use the full path to adb in the command line. For example:

```
c:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe install app.apk
```

Comment: Showing this message "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Comment: @Tarun adb.exe is in the platform-tools folder of your SDK.

Comment: @Tarun I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: Tp install apk in avd, just manually drag and drop the apk file in the opened emulated device

The same if you want to copy a file to the sd card

Comment: Ugh of course the drag and drop APK doesn't work for me. The "Installing APK" dialog comes up but it just keeps spinning. I'll have to try the ADB method but I've had issues connecting to the emulated device in the past. Why can't the easy method work for me? 